# User button processing

Tags: java, user-interface, processing

I am relatively new to programming, I have a pretty basic knowledge of VBA and matlab but for my uni design project I am required to produce a GUI which for certain reasons I have to do in processing. I tried to edit the example button to create two buttons that changed colour when you hover over them then change the background colour when clicked but it doesn't do anything.
The script is as follows:

```
PFont f;
int playX, playY; 
int stopX, stopY;
int buttonsize = 90;
color playColor, stopColor;
color playHighlight, stopHighlight;
boolean playOver = false;
boolean stopOver = false;
int n, i;

void setup() {
  size(800,500);
  f = createFont("Arial",16,true); // STEP 3 Create Font
  playColor = color(0);
  playHighlight = color(200);
  stopColor = color(0);
  stopHighlight = color(200);
  playX = (width/4)-(buttonsize/2);
  playY = 7*(height/10);
  stopX = (3*(width/4))-(buttonsize/2);
  stopY = 7*(height/10);
  n = 0;
  i = 0;
 }

void draw() {
  background(250);
  textFont(f,16);                 // STEP 4 Specify font to be used
  fill(0);                        // STEP 5 Specify font color 
  text("Set BPM:",width/10,2*(height/10));
  text("Choose File:",width/10,height/2);

    if (playOver) {
    fill(playHighlight);
  } else {
    fill(playColor);
  }
  stroke(0);
  rect(playX, playY, buttonsize, buttonsize);

  if (stopOver) {
    fill(stopHighlight);
  } else {
    fill(stopColor);
  }
  stroke(0);
  rect(stopX, stopY, buttonsize, buttonsize);
}

void update(int x, int y) {
  if (overplay(playX, playY, buttonsize, buttonsize)) {
    playOver = true;
    stopOver = false;
  } else if (overstop(stopX, stopY, buttonsize, buttonsize)) {
    stopOver = true;
    playOver = false;
   } else {
    stopOver = playOver = false;
  }
}

void mousePressed() {

  if (playOver) {
    if (i == 0) {
      i = 1;
      playColor = color(255,0,0);
    } else {
      i = 0;
      playColor = color(0);
    }
    }


   if (stopOver) {
    if (n == 0) {
      n = 1;
      stopColor = color(255,0,0);
    } else {
      n = 0;
      stopColor = color(0);
    }
  } 
 }



boolean overplay(int x, int y, int width, int height)  {
  if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width &&
      mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+height) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

boolean overstop(int x, int y,int width, int height) {
  if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width && 
      mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+height) {
     return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this Java????????????? Where is your main Class??? Where is the Listener Classes?

Comment: @AdnanAhmadKhan this is [processing](http://processing.org) a framework made in java. The pre-processor will make the main and everything...

Answer (score 0):

The code is a little confused. For one thing you never call `update()`, and this is the basic flaw. Add `update(0,0)` inside `draw()` and things will start to work : ).

You can use any number instead of 0 in `update()` call as those numbers are never used, better get rid if them. Also what's the point of having  `overStop()` and a `overPlay()` if you need to pass the parameters of each button to them? I think you should either make a unique `isOver(x,y,xw,yw)` and call it with each button parameters, or a `isOverStop()` that gets no parameter...

Well the better thing to do here is to make a Button class. this will make things much more clear and easy to maintain and write.

Another note, the way you are using `i` and `n` may be easier making them booleans and using the notation: `i = !i` which will toogle its state.

**Edit, sample code:**

```
Button play;


void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  background(255);
  play = new Button(50, 50, 30, 30);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  //display it...
  play.display();

  // using the button...
  if (play.isOn()) {
    fill(200, 30, 30);
    textSize(40);
    text("I'm playing!", 50, 200);
  }
}


void mouseClicked() {
  //listen for clicks
  play.update();
}



class Button {
  //coordinates
  int x, y, w, h;

  // state
  boolean on = false;

  //colors
  color[] colors = new color[4];

  Button(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h) {

    //init everything
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    w = _w;
    h = _h;

    //create some colors
    colors[0] = color(180); //off regular
    colors[1] = color(100); // off over
    colors[2] = color(180, 50, 180); // on
    colors[3] = color(100, 50, 100); // on over
  }


  void display() {
    // decide wich color to use
    fill(colorEngine());

    noStroke();

    //draw
    rect(x, y, w, h);
  }

  void update() {
    // toogle state
    if (isOver())
      on = !on;
  }

boolean isOn(){
  return on;
}

  color colorEngine() {
    if (!on) { // if off...
      if (!isOver()) { //and not over
        return colors[0];
      }
      else {//if off and over
        return colors[1];
      }
    }
    else {// if on...
      if (!isOver()) { //... and not over
        return colors[2];
      }
      else {// on and over
        return colors[3];
      }
    }
  }


  boolean isOver() {
    return mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+w &&
      mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+h;
  }
}//
```

Comment: I didnt really understand the overStop() stuff ect. I just copied it from the button example in the processing software. Using my understanding of programming I would have thought having an if function that asked if the mouse x and y coordinates where equal to that of the button would have been better.
What do you mean make a unique isOver? How do i do that?

Comment: I meant if you pass the coordinates to a function, then it can be reused by every button, so no point to repeat code... But OOP is much better approach. I edited the answer with a sample code of a rudimentary button class. Check it out ;)